# How to avoid poorly optimized code for Fortran array pointers?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, compiler-optimization, gfortran

I get rather poorly optimized assembly with gfortran 11.2 when using array pointers, even in seemingly very simple cases. For example, the optimized code (https://godbolt.org/z/eWo1oWzW3) for this function

```
subroutine test_ptr(x, y, n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, target, intent(in) :: x(n)
    integer, target, intent(out) :: y(n)

    integer, dimension(:), pointer, contiguous :: x_ptr, y_ptr
    x_ptr => x
    y_ptr => y
    y_ptr = x_ptr
endsubroutine
```

uses `malloc` for temporary storage in the assignment `y_ptr = x_ptr`, on any optimization level. Instead, I was hoping for basically the same assembly as the few lines (https://godbolt.org/z/rqsno6cjK) that are generated for the analogous version without array pointers:

```
subroutine test(x, y, n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, intent(in) :: x(n)
    integer, intent(out) :: y(n)
    y = x
endsubroutine
```

To me it seems like the compiler should be able to see that `x_ptr` and `y_ptr` are both trivial pointers to a range of contiguous memory, such that no temporary is necessary. But as can be seen in the original pass of the GCC Tree/RTL view (https://godbolt.org/z/Tajaezffs), a temporary is allocated and no optimization pass seems to be able to get rid of it.

A workaround I found is to `call test(x_ptr, y_ptr, n)` from `test_ptr` instead of using `=` directly (https://godbolt.org/z/YTx9hr9E3). That way, no `malloc` is generated in the original pass and the generated code is basically the same as without any array pointers.

---

Of course this all looks pretty silly in these toy examples, why would you even use array pointers in this case? But I actually encounter pretty much this setting when having to interop with C. To work with the data from the C world in Fortran, I have to call `C_F_POINTER`, for which I need an array pointer. So I have functions that look a bit like this

```
subroutine test_c(x_cptr, y_cptr, n)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(c_size_t), intent(in) :: n
    type(c_ptr), value :: x_cptr
    type(c_ptr), value :: y_cptr

    integer(c_int), dimension(:), pointer, contiguous :: x, y

    call c_f_pointer(x_cptr, x, [n])
    call c_f_pointer(y_cptr, y, [n])
    y = x
endsubroutine
```

and the generated code is basically the same as in the `test_ptr` case above (https://godbolt.org/z/zK9vG3zMG). As I have to work with a lot of C data, the mentioned workaround to write a `subroutine` that takes plain arrays for any operation that needs to be performed on the data is not really feasible for me. Therefore, I wonder whether there is a simpler way to help the compiler optimize away these array pointers.

---

**Edit:** I have since learned that this is indeed an aliasing issue combined with using the assigment operator for arrays. [This comment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4a1a72a89c65a6c1d01f717a20440d08c958a6e8/gcc/fortran/trans-array.cc#L37) in the gfortran source makes that pretty clear. An easy way to detect these cases (among others) is the warning option `-Warray-temporaries`. Unfortunately I do not see a way to convey that two array pointers may not alias, short of hacking [`gfc_could_be_alias`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4a1a72a89c65a6c1d01f717a20440d08c958a6e8/gcc/fortran/trans-array.cc#L4921) to always return `0` (which does remove the temporary in this case, but that really isn't a solution).

Comment: Remember, that `x` and `y` may overlap, if they are pointers or targets. Completely or incompletely. The usual aliasing restrictions no longer apply. And there is no `restrict` in Fortran because we can use plain non-pointer array arguments for that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict#Optimization

Comment: Incidentally, how does your C code cope with these optimizations?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, you appear to be saying that some elements of the explicit shape array dummy `x` can be modified even though the array is `intent(in)` through the dummy `y` when `x` has the TARGET attribute. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @francescalus I was mostly looking on the `test_c` case. The original might be a missed optimization. But hard to follow through the pointer.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава the difference in aliasing is an interesting point, I hadn't thought about that. Fits well to the observation that the workaround case generates `memmove` instead of `memcpy` (https://godbolt.org/z/YTx9hr9E3).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава as for my C code, it does not directly interact with Fortran functions like `test_c`. The data is allocated quite "far away" and only passed as opaque `c_ptr` through some layers of Fortran until it reaches `test_c`.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't similar code appear at some places in C?

Comment: Ok, `memcpy` can't be used for overlapping buffers, disregard. But in Fortran the compiler would have to test whether the arrays overlap. Amd it seems it currently does not do that.

Comment: If you post your "Edit:" as an answer it would be useful for future readers, and might get you an upvote or two. Also, your "Unfortunately..." might make a good further question, if you wanted to ask it.

Comment: @veryreverie I thought a lot about if "edit post", comment or answer would be best. I went with "edit post" because 1) the new info does not really answer the question. It does give some insight into why the code is poorly optimized, but not how to avoid that. The "Unfortunately..." part pretty much is the original question to my mind. And 2) the comment text box told me to edit my post if adding new information. I can see your point of view though, maybe if I change this question to "why" and post a new question for "how to avoid" that asks more specifically for the aliasing?

Comment: @mjacobse that's fair. I didn't mean to suggest your edit was invalid, just that you might get more traction from making a new question (although honestly, looking at the comments most of the relevant experts have already seen your post, so I'm not sure how much more traction you would get.)

Comment: You probably can just make a do loop and assign each element, but it is really just a workaround.